# MVC3 and breadcrumb navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

I try to create something like breadcrumb navigation using MVC3.

When user go to page he has for example: Home (id = 1), About (id = 2), and Hello (id = 3) links. These links I get from a database. When I click on Home I go to the database and get a  new set of links: Home -- Link1 (id = 3), Link2 (id = 4), etc.

If I not have nothing from database then I show some page content.

> Home -- Link1 -- Some Others
>
> Page Content

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have had success using the [MVC SiteMap project](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/)  for breadcrumb navigation.  If you cannot make use of this project directly for whatever reason, you could at least take a look at the source code to see how they implemented breadcrumbs.

The method that emits the breadcrumb navigation is: `Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()`

Comment: I've used this project before, love it.